# Backup a 750 GB HDD to an 1 TB external HD using Acronis and leave free space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, acronis-trueimage

Recently I've been thinking about buying an external HD to backup my laptop's drive. I'm thinking about using Acronis True Image to do that.

But I have one question:
The external drive I'm planing to buy is 1 TB. If I make a disk image backup of my 750 GB HDD, can I leave the extra 250 GB free as another partition, to use it as a normal USB drive?  If so, how?

And later, if I need to restore the image how will the software treat this extra partition? Can I select to backup the image of only the C: and D: partitions, leaving the E: (extra) alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an image, you image a partition not a whole device. And during the restore process you restore the partition. The extra 250GB on your 1TB drive will be left free during the imaging if you define a 750GB partition to where you store the image.